# Javascript permission denied error in IE , ActiveXObject is not defined in firefox while creating xml file

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, firefox, dom

I want to create xml file by DOM, that is what i wrote.
I run it in IE and it brings out a Permission denied error, and ActiveXObject is not defined in firefox in that line:

```
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

How can I fix that??

```
 var xhttp;
try {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
} catch (e) {
    try {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (f) {
    xhttp = null;
    }
}
if (!xhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xhttp.open("GET", "nn.xml", false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

newel = xmlDoc.createElement("student");
newtext = xmlDoc.createElement("stName");
newel.appendChild(newtext);
newtext2 = xmlDoc.createElement("examName");
newel.appendChild(newtext2);
newtext3 = xmlDoc.createElement("grade");
newel.appendChild(newtext3);
x = xmlDoc.documentElement;
x.appendChild(newel);
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
ts = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\\test\\test\\nn.xml", 2, true, -1); //2=Open a file for writing.
ts.Write(xmlDoc.xml);
ts.Close();
```

Comment: It would be easier to use a framework's Ajax functions (like jQuery). But you won't be able to do the second part of your script (writing to a local file) at all in Firefox

Comment: yes, but I actually have to have a local file to do some operations on it.

Comment: @noor well, it still won't work in Firefox.

Comment: @noor, if you're not allowed to write the file, it doesn't matter if you *have* to have it or not; it won't be there. And it would be a major security hole if you could access any folder you want on the browser's machine; malicious JavaScript or VBScript could erase everything on the drive or put spyware/malware everywhere.

Comment: ... Which is why activeX is the devil.

Comment: Anyway, this jQuery toolkit will work in all browsers: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ unless it's for learning purposes, I would highly recommend using that.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveX is for Microsoft browsers only, you should NOT be using that if you want cross browser compatibility.

As for writing to a file, this is not allowed for a good reason. Consider how many times your hard-drive would have been erased while surfing random internet sites, if this was allowed.